# Running Java 32bit and 64bit on same computer

Tags: 64-bit, java, 32-bit, vuze

I ran into a rather puzzling problem, trying to install Vuze 4.2.0.2 on my Windows 7. I have a Java 6 JDK 64bit, but Vuze complains that it can't find a correct 32bit JRE. Yet, as far as I know it shouldn't matter which Java is installed on the computer. (See also [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783662/java-32-bit-vs-64-bit-compatibility)).

Now I was wondering :

1. if it makes sense running a 32bit and a 64bit Java on the same machine,
2. Whether that is possible, and if so
3. what I should pay attention to in order to make sure that the correct Java is found.

Thank you in advance

PS : I have my reasons no to use the latest Vuze, so please don't tell me to update Vuze. I know.

Comment: While for pure Java programs it doesn't matter which JRE is installed, some programs use external libraries which may require 32bit or 64bit JRE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need JDK to run Vuze, JRE should suffice. Apparently it does matter which Java is installed on the computer. I had a similar issue with 64bit Internet Explorer. So:

1. Yes, it does
2. Yes, it is possible to [install both JREs](http://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp)
3. You don't need to pay attention, it should find the appropriate version automatically.

Comment: I know I only need JRE, but I'm developing in Java sometimes as well. Then the JDK comes in handy :-) Thx for the answer.